# How do I stop or at least partly reduce the number of times I need to type in my Apple password

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, books, apple-music

I use iBooks, the app store, Apple Music and iTunes on my mac and iphone.

Apple asks me for my password at least twice a week on each device.

Does it anyone know how to prevent this?

Scenarios: 
+ I simply open iBooks on my Mac
+ I am listening to Apple Music
+ I open my iPhone with touch ID

I am not even buying anything.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Apple will automatically sign you out of their apps if not being used for a specific period of time (I'm thinking that's 48-60 hours but not sure).  Of course, that's per app, per device.

Comment: 48 hours? So if I don't read for 48 hours it signs me out of iBooks. That insane and bizarre

Comment: That timeframe was just a guess.  I know it happens to me once or twice a week because I'm moving between multiple devices all the time.